# How to pass name of the host into tick script .exec() event handler

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor, chronograf

I am currently working in tick script, I want to pass host name as an argument when alert triggers from that specific host, so I am unable to find the exact variable to pass to that script.

```
            var trigger = data
                |alert()
                    .crit(lambda: "value" > crit)
                    .message(message)
                    .id(idVar)
                    .idTag(idTag)
                    .levelTag(levelTag)
                    .messageField(messageField)
                    .durationField(durationField)
                    .exec('/usr/bin/python', '/home/scripts/pythons/memory.py' ) // here need to pass host name
```

Comment: what do you mean by `host`? do you mean a field/tag, or the name of that alert script?

Answer (score 0):

in front of `var trigger`, you have `var name` for name of that scipt, just pass `string(name)` inside `.exec` as the second argument